# What kind of Neural network to use for classifing a dotted image to a number depending on the number of and size of dots?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am currently trying to train a CNN to classify images that consists of dots to a class where the class is a value depending on the number and size of the dots. More dots should be in a high number class and less dots a low number class.

I wonder if there is an alternative to a CNN for this task. I just started designing a CNN since it was an image problem but then realized that the difference to other object classification problems in images is that these images don't really have the same properties, like edges for example, that object images have.

The main goal is to get a number out of the network when the input is an image of this kind and I don't have a preference of how to do it except that it must be a Machine learning solution.

This is how the images look. I have the possibility to use two different kinds where one is the original and the other is binary grayscale black and white.

[Binary black and white image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JvvX.jpg)

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uY38.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can convert image to binary, where pixel will have 0 and 1, assume 0 is background and 1 is the dots. you can sum all the 1`s in that image to get class of yours, to normalize output you can divide it but some number.

if you want machine learning solution then just feed that binary image to a single Dense layer, and it will be a regression problem not classification.
your output activation function should be RELU, and loss function MSE.